# How to use stacks instead of recursion?

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, stack

I'm trying to use stacks instead of recursion. I reviewed the similar answers and they seem fine but I really do not get it. All I make is make the code worse. 
I'm trying to use stacks on the following code which is taken from :http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-3-n-queen-problem/
The following code implements n queens problem recursively with backtracking and it works fine. I just need to use stacks instead of recursion. I thought the backtracking algorithm would be a good idea to use stacks to create the recursion.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
#define N 4
#include<stdio.h>

/* A utility function to print solution */
void printSolution(int board[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %d ", board[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/* A utility function to check if a queen can be placed on board[row][col]
   Note that this function is called when "col" queens are already placeed
   in columns from 0 to col -1. So we need to check only left side for
   attacking queens */
bool isSafe(int board[N][N], int row, int col)
{
    int i, j;

    /* Check this row on left side */
    for (i = 0; i < col; i++)
    {
        if (board[row][i])
            return false;
    }

    /* Check upper diagonal on left side */
    for (i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--)
    {
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;
    }

    /* Check lower diagonal on left side */
    for (i = row, j = col; j >= 0 && i < N; i++, j--)
    {
        if (board[i][j])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/* A recursive utility function to solve N Queen problem */
bool solveNQUtil(int board[N][N], int col)
{
    /* base case: If all queens are placed then return true */
    if (col >= N)
        return true;

    /* Consider this column and try placing this queen in all rows
       one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        /* Check if queen can be placed on board[i][col] */
        if ( isSafe(board, i, col) )
        {
            /* Place this queen in board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 1;

            /* recur to place rest of the queens */
            if ( solveNQUtil(board, col + 1) == true )
                return true;

            /* If placing queen in board[i][col] doesn't lead to a solution
               then remove queen from board[i][col] */
            board[i][col] = 0; // BACKTRACK
        }
    }

     /* If queen can not be place in any row in this colum col
        then return false */
    return false;
}

/* This function solves the N Queen problem using Backtracking.  It mainly uses
solveNQUtil() to solve the problem. It returns false if queens cannot be placed,
otherwise return true and prints placement of queens in the form of 1s. Please
note that there may be more than one solutions, this function prints one of the
feasible solutions.*/
bool solveNQ()
{
    int board[N][N] = { {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    if ( solveNQUtil(board, 0) == false )
    {
      printf("Solution does not exist");
      return false;
    }

    printSolution(board);
    return true;
}

// driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    solveNQ();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us the problem here.  i.e. what is wrong with this code?  What are the symptoms?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Where's the stack? Using stacks instead of recursion is doing recursion manually, so to speak, as you popping of the stack is the same as the stack unwinding.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're right. I edited it now.

Comment: It is a bit confusing as recursion is actually using the stack, piling up the recursive calls as @ChiefTwoPencils said.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes I'm trying to do recursion manually. I will push the element and if it's not placeable then pop it and try the next one. And if after the board is all done but there are not N queens placed in that position then I need to backtrack by popping from stack and retry with new positions.

Comment: Read about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) & [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style); it is the canonical framework for your question....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that at each recursion you are testing the next column. you already have some kind of stack in your board, col being your stack pointer.

considering you have only one queen by col you can even reduce the size of the required head space.

```
const int size=5; // your board size
int isSafe(const int pos[size],const int col,const int row) {
    for(int i=0;i<col;i++) { //check up to the stack pointer ( anything beyond is garbage )
        if(pos[i]==row){ //check on same row
            return 0;
        }
        //check diagonals
        int delta=col-i;
        if(pos[i]==(row+delta)) { 
            return 0;
        }
        if(pos[i]==(row-delta)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int solveNQ() {
    int pos[size];
    int col=0;
    int row=0;
    while(col<size) {
        if(isSafe(pos,col,row)) {
            pos[col]=row;
            col++;
            row=0;
        }else{
            row++;
            while(row==size) { // rollback to previous while end of col
                if(col==0) { 
                    // we seem to have found no reasonable solution
                    // as we rolled back further
                    return 0;
                }
                col--; 
                row=pos[col]+1; // pop previous position and try the next one
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int main() {
    solveNQ();
    return 0;
}
```

this is solving your problem in an pseudo recursive way